# How to output in ElasticSearch distance for same location that chosen by geo_distance from multiple locations

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, geolocation

I have multiple locations:

- Document 1 -

  "contact": [
  {
      "address": {
          "geolocation": {
              "lon": -73.5409,
              "lat": 41.2512
          }
      }
  }
  ]
- Document 2 -

  {   "contact": [
  {
      "address": {
          "geolocation": {
              "lon": -73.7055,
              "lat": 40.6744
          }
      }
  },
  {
      "address": [
          {
              "geolocation": {
                  "lon": -73.9325,
                  "lat": 40.7482
              }
          },
          {
              "geolocation": {
                  "lon": -87.9921,
                  "lat": 42.9959
              }
          },
          {
              "geolocation": {
                   "lon": -95.4563,
                   "lat": 29.8775
              }
          }
      ]
  }
  ]
  }

geo_distance finds both documents by closest location.

```
"geo_distance": {
"distance": "275mi",
"distance_type": "plane",
"contact.address.geolocation": {
    "lat": 42,
    "lon": -71
    },
"unit": "mi"
}
```

}

But when I add script field to output lat, lon, and distance

```
"script_fields": {
"distance_value": {
    "script": "doc.containsKey('contact.address.geolocation') ? doc['contact.address.geolocation'].value ? doc['contact.address.geolocation'].arcDistanceInMiles(42.2882,-71.0474)  : null : null"
    },
"geolocation": {
    "script": "doc.containsKey('contact.address.geolocation') ? doc['contact.address.geolocation'].value : null"
    }
}
```

it output random geolocation element from Document 2.
For document 1 it is 147 miles
But for document 2 it is 1601 miles because it takes different location than in geo_distance filter.

How can I print same value as in geo_distance? I want to show distance to my point.

I've tried this script:

```
"script_fields": {
"distance_value": {
    "script": "if (doc.containsKey('contact.address.geolocation')==false) return null; min = 40000; for(e in doc['contact.address.geolocation']){ c=0; if(e!=null) c = e.arcDistanceInMiles(42.2882,-71.0474); if(c<min) min=c;}; return min;"
    }
}
```

It gives error 
**No signature of method: org.elasticsearch.common.geo.GeoPoint.arcDistanceInMiles() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double)**
Also I don't think it will iterate over all gelocation fields.

Comment: it works that way because your `contact` field is not nested, hence there i no "order" in the geolocation addresses, one of them matches, but the script will take the first one to perform the computation. You need to iterate over each location and sort them by distance.

Comment: I've tried to iterate in the script to calculate all distances but it did not work for me. Can you help with example of script? I was not able find such one anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: Update your question with the new script you came up with and we'll start from there

Comment: Why do you have a `resume` field all of a sudden?

Comment: It was typo. Sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I found only one way to output same distance as in the filter -  add "sort" element:

```
"sort": [ 
    "_score",
    {
        "_geo_distance": {
            "contact.address.geolocation": [
                 -71,
                 42
            ],
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "mi"
        }
    }
]
```